# 100s of tabs web browser Android

Tags: android, web-browser

On my iPhone I have roughly 80-100 tabs open at a time.

I use it a basically as my primary device(no laptop).  I would effectively use the same number of tabs on my laptop also.

My iPhone snaps pictures of the web page and does a tremendous job of memory management such that everything is very smooth.

Is there a browser like this?  When I attempt to have this number of tabs open on Android it grinds to a halt.